# Add "- All" as default parameter in my SSRS binary parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, binary, ssrs-2008

I have some parameter in a SSRS. I add a "- All" parameter as default value in all of them. For one parameter, a binary one, this cause this error :

> - Syntax error converting the nvarchar value '- All' to a column of data type bit.

Here is my Query :

```
SELECT mValue.value AS V
FROM FROM SERVER.DB.dbo.table mValue
UNION
SELECT '- All' 
FROM SERVER.DB.dbo.table mValue
```

I need to get 3 choices in my selector : - All, True, False

Here's my correction, Thank's to the help :

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, mValue.value) AS V
FROM FROM SERVER.DB.dbo.table mValue
UNION
SELECT '- All' 
FROM SERVER.DB.dbo.table mValue
```

Comment: The two selects'  column data types must be compatible.

Comment: Another way to add a noChoice value in my selector after the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you should change the parameter type into String instead.